# Deployed ruby on rails on shared hosting - routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shared-hosting

I'm a rails newbie. I'm struggling to get a simple helloworld rails app(no db) working on on shared hosting.

development.log

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 122.61.170.222 at 2012-12-17 17:46:09) [GET]

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/Say/hello" with {:method=>:get}):


Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)
```

My rails setup: http://scifiwear.com/rails_setup.png

[rails setup http://scifiwear.com/rails_setup.png](http://scifiwear.com/rails_setup.png)

My subdomain setup: http://scifiwear.com/subdomain.png

[subdomain setup http://scifiwear.com/subdomain.png](http://scifiwear.com/subdomain.png)

Server versions:

Ruby Version : 1.8.7
Gem Version : 1.8.16
Rails is 2.3.14

Steps I took to configure helloWorld app:

1. Created app using web form http://scifiwear.com/rails_setup.png
2. cd myapp14
3. ruby script/generate controller Say hello goodbye
4. http://myapp14.scifiwear.com/  HAPPY!

5 http://myapp14.scifiwear.com/say/hello NOT HAPPY!

mongrel.log:

```
Mon Dec 17 17:46:09 -0600 2012: Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #<NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.split>
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:52:in `dispatch_cgi'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:101:in `dispatch_cgi'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Last 4 lines of my routes.rb: (untouched)

```
# consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources.

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end
```

Any suggestions appreciated thanks.

Comment: can you post your entire routes.rb and the controller action in question? please check out <http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html>

Comment: Everything in the routes.rb is commented out except the first line and the last 3 lines as seen above. It's a default routes.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the answers given for this previous question : [Problems running Ruby on Rails apps on shared hosted server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911852/problems-running-ruby-on-rails-apps-on-shared-hosted-server); they might be helpful in this case.

I tried reproducing the same error locally, with `rails 2.3.14` and `ruby 1.8.7-p371`; didn't get the error message. The routes file is similar to what you have.

The log trace is as follows:

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Users/hallelujah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@hallelujah/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /Users/hallelujah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@hallelujah/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server


Processing SayController#hello (for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-20 15:52:23) [GET]
Rendering say/hello
Completed in 35ms (View: 34, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://localhost/say/hello]
```

Given that the ruby & rails versions are very old on this hosted server, it might be difficult for you to get help on issues faced with this installation. And you would face difficulty in learning the concepts as well.

My advise would be for you to switch to using the latest version of ruby & rails (and learn about the best practices of web development with rails), by following the excellent & freely available online book by Michael Hartl : [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial)

Comment: Prakash I was super impressed you tried to reproduce the error with the same version numbers! I think your advice is good. I'm contacting my hosting company now to to see if they can help me fix this. If not I'll go to a dedicated rails hoster with latest versions. Good on you. Thanks. : )